# HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid. On IIS when using `AllowedHosts` appsettings property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I get the error HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid. on swagger when configuring CORS using the AllowedHost property.

```cs
var origins = Configuration["AllowedHosts"].Split(";");

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(origins)
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

But if I use a different property like `Test` swagger gets loaded fine.

```cs
var origins = Configuration["Test"].Split(";");
```

appsettings.Development.json

```json
{
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "http://localhost:3000;https://localhost:44308"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm stupid, I was trying to use [AllowedHosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/host-filtering?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to configure Allowed Origins

Answer (score 0):

You should split your URLs in origin's variable with `,` then use it in your rest CorePolicy code.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(String.Join(",", origins))
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't wan to hard code the urls, I want them in the settings file

Comment: try this as well. but seemingly you could solve the problem.